Using file.choose to select a specific "sheet" from an .xlsx file
Looking for a pop up GUI that the user can select both an .xlsx file and sheet to load into the Global Environment.
I am using the following to open and load a file into Global Environment in RStudio:
data <- read_excel(path = file.choose())
This works to load the file but will always default to sheet 1.  Is there anyway to have the user select not only the the file but the specific sheet as well using this same popup?  I assume I could use something like "tcltk" to write an interface to do this, but did not want to go to this much trouble.

Not a "pop up GUI" but once you could use file.choose to identify the file, then use excel_sheets to print out a list of the sheets, allowing the user to specify which sheet is desired, then use the sheet argument to read_excel to open that sheet in that file.

One option is a Shiny gadget.
